# Google Calendar Insert event

Tags: java, google-calendar-api

I don't know how insert a event in a calendar. In my website, you can login with google, and then you can insert a event in YOUR calendar, but as explained in Google Calendar API, I need send my ClientID and my ClientSecret and I want use your ID. I don't know how build a service.

```
public void setUp() throws IOException {
HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

// The clientId and clientSecret can be found in Google Developers Console
String clientId = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID";
String clientSecret = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET";

// Or your redirect URL for web based applications.
String redirectUrl = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";
String scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar";

// Step 1: Authorize -->
String authorizationUrl = new GoogleAuthorizationRequestUrl(clientId, redirectUrl, scope)
    .build();

// Point or redirect your user to the authorizationUrl.
System.out.println("Go to the following link in your browser:");
System.out.println(authorizationUrl);

// Read the authorization code from the standard input stream.
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.println("What is the authorization code?");
String code = in.readLine();
// End of Step 1 <--

// Step 2: Exchange -->
AccessTokenResponse response = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeGrant(httpTransport, jsonFactory,
    clientId, clientSecret, code, redirectUrl).execute();
// End of Step 2 <--

GoogleAccessProtectedResource accessProtectedResource = new GoogleAccessProtectedResource(
    response.accessToken, httpTransport, jsonFactory, clientId, clientSecret,
    response.refreshToken);

Calendar service = new Calendar(httpTransport, accessProtectedResource, jsonFactory);
service.setApplicationName("YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME");
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

ClientID identifies the application and you should create one in the developer console. The next step is getting an Oauth token for the user whose calendar you would like to access. The whole process is described here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth